# How to style a table-like div with css? How to fill a "column"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make something like this inside a bootstrap column:

[image: The target image is like this]

The best I can do is this, using html like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 event-date-container">
       <p class="event-date">OCT 4</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
       <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
       <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 event-date-container">
       <p class="event-date">OCT 18</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
       <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
       <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan belantara, serigala B menantang serigala A</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

With css:

```
event-date {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: #222222;
}
event-date-container {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

And color text green to give the color green is this:

[image: What I am able to do right now]

How to fill the first column with full background colour? Any other trick I can use to improve this?

Comment: try adding `height:100%` to `.event-date`

Comment: @KhanhTO doesn't works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with the default Bootstrap grid system. Each `.col-*-*` will take only the height it needs, since it is `float`ed.

If possible, I would use a table styling to achieve what you want. Since what you are doing *is* a table, why not simply use the Bootstrap table styling?

### Using `<table>`

http://jsfiddle.net/spjm90cf/1/

The HTML:

```
<table class="table event-table">
    <tr>
       <td class="event-date-container">
           <p class="event-date">OCT 4</p>
       </td>
       <td>
           <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
           <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan</p>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="event-date-container">
           <p class="event-date">OCT 18</p>
       </td>
       <td>
           <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
           <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan belantara, serigala B menantang serigala A</p>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Remove Bootstrap's dividing lines */
.event-table > tbody > tr > td {
    border-width: 0;
}

.event-date {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: #222222;
}
.event-date-container {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

### Manipulating the grid system

http://jsfiddle.net/spjm90cf/2/

If you cannot use a table for some reason, here is a way of styling your `.row`s and `.col-*-*`s into a table-like structure:

The HTML (you will need a container to act as the "table"):

```
<div class="container-table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2 event-date-container">
           <p class="event-date">OCT 4</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
           <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
           <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2 event-date-container">
           <p class="event-date">OCT 18</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
           <p class="color-text-green">ALL CAMPUSES</p>
           <p>Ada dua ekor serigala di hutan belantara, serigala B menantang serigala A</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container-table {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
}

.container-table .row {
    display: table-row;
}

.container-table [class^="col-"] {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}

.event-date {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: #222222;
}
.event-date-container {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended using the table one, and it does make more sense to make it as table.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be just to use flexbox:

```
.row { display: flex; }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14095/

Although you may want to change your html/css. Here is a nice article about using flexbox for filling the height of the parent container: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

Answer (score 0):

I will try with this:

```
.row > div:first-child {
/* your code */
}
```

This code will add attributes for every first div in div with class "row"